# jQuery Calculate remaining characters length for input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a dozen input, each with a different maximum length

I would like to display this authorized number of characters to the right of these input in the div `characters` (when we click in)

Then hide it when you leave the input

The problem is that I can not get out the variable maxLenght to send it in the keyup function, so I get every key the `maxlength`

How can I proceed to avoid all this?

```js
$("input").focus(function() {
  var block = $(this).parent()
  var maxLength = $(this).attr('maxlength');

  var length = $(this).val().length;
  var length = maxLength - length;
  block.find(".characters").show().text(length);
  // return maxLength
});

$('input').keyup(function() {
  var block = $(this).parent()
  var maxLength = $(this).attr('maxlength');

  var length = $(this).val().length;
  var length = maxLength - length;
  block.find(".characters").show().text(length);
});

$("input").focusout(function() {
  $(this).next('.characters').text('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-title">Code 1</div>
    <input type="search" name="code_1" id="code-1" class="form-control dymax" value="000" placeholder="Code 1" autocomplete="none" maxlength="5">
    <div class="characters"></div>
    <div class="input-content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-title">Code 2</div>
    <input type="search" name="code_2" id="code-2" class="form-control dymax" value="000" placeholder="Code 2" autocomplete="none" maxlength="20">
    <div class="characters"></div>
    <div class="input-content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-title">Code 3</div>
    <input type="search" name="code_3" id="code-3" class="form-control dymax" value="000" placeholder="Code 3" autocomplete="none" maxlength="10">
    <div class="characters"></div>
    <div class="input-content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-title">Code 4</div>
    <input type="search" name="code_4" id="code-4" class="form-control dymax" value="000" placeholder="Code 4" autocomplete="none" maxlength="5">
    <div class="characters"></div>
    <div class="input-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What isn't working for you?

Comment: There is no way to get the ``maxlength`` variable out of ``focus`` to avoid retrieving this variable with each key pressed ?

Comment: Remove the duplicate code with multiple events `$( "input" ).on('keyup focus change", function() {` and chain with `}).on('focusout',function(){...`

Comment: What does the above code not do that you need?

Comment: If retrieving the maxlength on focus/keyup each time is *really* causing you issues, then you have much bigger issues.  ie don't worry about micro-optimising this.  (slightly more efficient would be to use `.data("maxlength")` and `data-maxlength="5"` as it would be cached within jquery - but you will not notice the difference).

Comment: @Rocstar I've answered to Your question. but `"characters to the right"` - I hope You can do css work Yourself

Comment: @num8er Thank you ! It works perfectly (+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want this one:

```js
$("input").on('focus keyup', function() {
  var $input = $(this);
  var value = $input.val();
  var maxLength = parseInt($input.attr('maxlength'));
  var remainingLength = maxLength - value.length;
  if (remainingLength < 0) {
    $input.val(value.substr(0, maxLength));
    remainingLength = 0;
  }
  $input.next().show().text(remainingLength);
});

$("input").focusout(function() {
  $(this).next().text('');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-title">Code 1</div>
    <input type="search" name="code_1" id="code-1" class="form-control dymax" value="000" placeholder="Code 1" autocomplete="none" maxlength="5">
    <div class="characters"></div>
    <div class="input-content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-title">Code 2</div>
    <input type="search" name="code_2" id="code-2" class="form-control dymax" value="000" placeholder="Code 2" autocomplete="none" maxlength="20">
    <div class="characters"></div>
    <div class="input-content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-title">Code 3</div>
    <input type="search" name="code_3" id="code-3" class="form-control dymax" value="000" placeholder="Code 3" autocomplete="none" maxlength="10">
    <div class="characters"></div>
    <div class="input-content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-title">Code 4</div>
    <input type="search" name="code_4" id="code-4" class="form-control dymax" value="000" placeholder="Code 4" autocomplete="none" maxlength="5">
    <div class="characters"></div>
    <div class="input-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "characters to the right" - use a span not a div perhaps?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss it's not my html, I've just used question author's html and js and answered to question

Comment: oh, he added extra "feature"

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss `"characters to the right"` is just in his extra css. basically question was: how to get maxlength and I've done it and made to not overflow the maxlength

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors with multiple `var length`, you can also simplify the code.  I would also put a custom event on the trailing `.characters` instead of on the input and then trigger that.

Note that by doing it this way you can include the "search" event fired when you click the little `x` on an input to clear it.

I added a custom event and passed to that a flag to show/hide in the same function when it is triggered.

I made the `div` a `span` to show it to the right.

```js
$("input.form-control").on('focus keyup change search', function() {
  var block = $(this).closest('.input-block');
  block.find(".characters").trigger('custom', ["show"]);
}).on('focusout', function(event) {
  var block = $(this).closest('.input-block');
  var chars = block.find(".characters");
  chars.trigger('custom', ["hide"]);
});
$('.characters').on('custom', function(event, dowhat) {
  let displayMe = dowhat === "show" ? true : false;
  let charTxt = $(this);
  if (displayMe) {
    let block = $(this).closest('.input-block');
    let blockInput = block.find("input.form-control");
    let maxLength = blockInput.attr('maxlength');

    let currentLength = blockInput.val().length;
    let allowedLength = maxLength - currentLength;
    charTxt.text(allowedLength + "");
  }
  charTxt.toggle(displayMe);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="input-block col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-title">Code 1</div>
    <input type="search" name="code_1" id="code-1" class="form-control dymax" value="000" placeholder="Code 1" autocomplete="none" maxlength="5">
    <span class="characters"></span>
    <div class="input-content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-block col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-title">Code 2</div>
    <input type="search" name="code_2" id="code-2" class="form-control dymax" value="000" placeholder="Code 2" autocomplete="none" maxlength="20">
    <span class="characters"></span>
    <div class="input-content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-block col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-title">Code 3</div>
    <input type="search" name="code_3" id="code-3" class="form-control dymax" value="000" placeholder="Code 3" autocomplete="none" maxlength="10">
    <span class="characters"></span>
    <div class="input-content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-block col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-title">Code 4</div>
    <input type="search" name="code_4" id="code-4" class="form-control dymax" value="000" placeholder="Code 4" autocomplete="none" maxlength="5">
    <span class="characters"></span>
    <div class="input-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```